# JavaFX show AnchorPane from Thread

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx

I am trying to create the following concept: start a thread whenever a specific screen gets launched. The thread should receive a message which is called a "tag", which is not working yet so I got it hardcoded. 
Then show an AnchorPane based on the validation of the tag: either the showError or showValid function. However, the application first runs the function and then shows the AnchorPane and the updated ListView.

I want to start the following thread whenever a specific screen launches.

```
public class RFIDThread extends Thread{
       private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(RFIDApplication.class);

        /**
        * The incoming data stream from the LLRP reader connection
        */
       private DataInputStream inStream = null;

       /**
        * The socket for the connection to the LLRP Reader
        */
       private Socket socket = null;

       /**
        * A queue to store incoming LLRP Messages
        */
       private LinkedBlockingQueue<LLRPMessage> queue = null;

       private String[] found_tags = new String[5];

       private JSONArray valid_tags;

       private TagsListController controller;

       /**
        * Thread for constant reading of the stream
        * 
         * @param socket
         * @param controller
         * @param tags
         * @param orderNumber
         * @throws java.io.IOException
        */
       public RFIDThread(Socket socket, TagsListController controller, JSONArray tags, String orderNumber) throws IOException {
            this.socket = socket;
            this.controller = controller;
            this.queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<LLRPMessage>();

            try {
                this.inStream = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                logger.error("Cannot get input stream", e);
            }

            valid_tags = tags;

            found_tags[0] = "aga9jrjahr";
            found_tags[1] = "agahs4suj";
            found_tags[2] = "a79gtvaTGBQG";
            found_tags[3] = "at3anit08av9agq4";
            //found_tags[4] = "4a05355d0000000000017cc0";

            //start();
       }

       @Override
       public void run() 
       {
           super.run();
            if (socket.isConnected()) {
                for (String found_tag : found_tags) {
                    Integer index = valid_tags.indexOf(found_tag);
                    if (index > 0) {
                        Platform.runLater(() -> {
                            controller.showValid(found_tag);
                        });
                    } else {
                        Platform.runLater(() -> {
                            controller.showError(found_tag);
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
       }
}
```

The thread should run functions: showError or showValid based on the tag it receives. Currently I have some hardcoded tags set-up which are all invalid so it should run the showError() function. This function: adds the tag to a ListView, sets the tag as text of a label, display the AnchorPane, sleep 1 second, hide the AnchorPane and then sleep 1 second. After this, the next tag must be processed.

```
/**
* Display red screen
* @param tag
*/
public void showError(String tag) {
    this.found_tags_list.getItems().add(tag);
    this.errorTag.setText(tag);
    System.out.println(errorTag.getText());
    this.errorPane.setVisible(true);
    pause(1000);
    this.validPane.setVisible(false);
    pause(1000);
}
```

Comment: If `pause(...)` does what I assume it does, you are blocking the FX Application Thread (because `showError(...)` is executed on that thread). That will prevent the UI from being rendered until the entire `showError(...)` method, including its pauses, is complete. If you want to do something UI-based after a pause, then use a [`PauseTransition`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/animation/PauseTransition.html). It's not clear what the purpose of the second pause is, since nothing happens after it. (Also, you presumably mean `this.errorPane.setVisible(false);`?)

Comment: You could also just move the pauses to the background thread and have `hideError()` and `hideValid()` methods in the controller, which you call via `Platform.runLater(...)` from that thread.

Comment: The methods are in the controller, that is why I pass the controller to the thread so it can call these methods.

Comment: How is that relevant to my comment?

Comment: You are saying: "move the pauses to the background thread and have hideError() in the controller". I am already doing that or I am misunderstanding you completely.

Comment: You are misunderstanding me (or maybe misunderstanding your own code). The pauses are not in the background thread - they are in the controller (and being run on the FX Application Thread). That is why you are not seeing the UI update until the pauses have finished, as I already explained. So *either* replace the pauses with proper use of a `PauseTransition` *or* move the pauses to the background thread.

Comment: @James_D would you mind showing me some example code of how I should be doing this? I have no clue and i'm out of ideas.

Comment: When I am back at my computer. But it's hard for me to understand why you can't just follow the simple instruction "move the pause to the background thread".

Comment: Added an answer, not sure what is there that I haven't already posted in comments.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't post the code for your `pause()` method, so I'm going to assume it does something like `Thread.sleep(...)` and handles the interrupted exception appropriately. I.e. I'm going to assume you have something like:

```
public void pause(int millis) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(millis);
    } catch (InterruptedException exc) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }
}
```

The `showError()` method is being (explicitly) executed on the FX Application Thread. That thread is also responsible for rendering the UI. Consequently, the UI can't be redrawn while the `showError()` method is executing (because a single thread can't do two things at once: that's basically the definition of "thread").

So it's *always* an error to block the FX Application Thread, because it makes the UI unresponsive and prevents it from being drawn.

If you are already on the FX Application Thread, and want to schedule some code to execute in the future, you can do that with a `PauseTransition`. So instead of

```
this.errorPane.setVisible(true);
pause(1000);
this.validPane.setVisible(false);
```

you can do

```
this.errorPane.setVisible(true);
PauseTransition pause = new PauseTransition(Duration.millis(1000));
pause.setOnFinished(e -> this.validPane.setVisible(false));
pause.play();
```

The second `pause` in that method makes less sense. It simply pauses the FX Application Thread, and then the method exits, so there is nothing it is waiting for anyway.

If the idea is to make the background thread pause at that point, you should call `pause()` on the background thread. (Calling it on the FX Application Thread, obviously, won't make the background thread pause anyway.)

So I think your code should look like:

```
public class RFIDThread extends Thread {

    // ...

   @Override
   public void run() {
       super.run();
        if (socket.isConnected()) {
            for (String found_tag : found_tags) {
                Integer index = valid_tags.indexOf(found_tag);
                if (index > 0) {
                    Platform.runLater(() -> controller.showValid(found_tag));
                } else {
                    Platform.runLater(() -> controller.showError(found_tag));
                }

                pause(2000);
            }
        }
   }

}
```

Note that I'm guessing here the intention is for your background thread to pause for (approximately) one second *after* the pane you show is hidden again, which would mean it needs to pause for two seconds in total.

In the controller, you do

```
public void showError(String tag) {
    this.found_tags_list.getItems().add(tag);
    this.errorTag.setText(tag);
    System.out.println(errorTag.getText());
    this.errorPane.setVisible(true);
    PauseTransition pause = new PauseTransition(Duration.millis(1000));
    pause.setOnFinished(e -> this.validPane.setVisible(false));
    pause.play();
}
```